# The value for targetId in Community1/variations/userProfileDataAccessRequestComponent.json isn't valid. Check the value and try again

Tags: lightning-experience, json, vs-code, experience-builder-page, experience-bundle

I have enabled Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API and tried to retrieve a Experience Bundle community via VS Code but obtained an error.

```
The value for targetId in Community1/variations/userProfileDataAccessRequestComponent.json isn't valid. Check the value and try again.
```

I can't find any documentation on how to get around this or to change this json file in the config folder. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what version of the metadata api are you using in VsCode - I'd make sure it was current